# Why is `foo is not { } bar` not semantically equivalent to `!(foo is { } bar)`?

Tags: c#, .net, pattern-matching

Let's have `string foo` variable in C#.

Why are the following statements not semantically equivalent?

```
if (!(foo is { } bar) || bar.Length == 0)
```

and

```
if (foo is not { } bar || bar.Length == 0)
```

---

For `foo = null`, both appear to behave identically.

```
var foo = null;

if (!(foo is { } bar) || bar.Length == 0)
{
    Console.WriteLine("bar");
}
  
if (foo is not { } baz || baz.Length == 0)
{
    Console.WriteLine("baz");
}
```

But for `foo = "something"`, the first statement works, but the second fails with `NullReferenceException`.

Check [sharplab](https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LgTgrgdgNAJiA1AHwAICYCMBYAUHgNwEMwACAMwHtLSBeUgIgGdKBbAU2AAsBLKAcwYBuPHh7lSACgCEkqjR5NSAb1IBfUgCMSASlLJkWkgDoAMuwHc69AAw68yvKWelUmAJySG2sAx0jcNSdSMQk5alJFUihKYBV1IwAvfUNtRLMLfitaW3tcR1wXVw8vNL8AtSA=).

Is it a feature?

**Edit:** It seems that it was a bug: https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/51996#issuecomment-803508111

Comment: Which equivalence do you expect?

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski That both produce same IL.

Comment: Could you be running into an issue with [definite assignment](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/variables#definite-assignment)? [Per the docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-9.0/patterns3#variable-definitions-and-definite-assignment), pattern variables are only considered *definitely assigned* when the `is` pattern is true. [The changelog](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-9.0/patterns3) links to a number of git issues on the subject.

Comment: _"That both produce same IL"_ -- what IL does each produce? Is the IL different in any _material_ way? Which IL did you expect, and why do you consider the alternative IL unexpected? It's a little surprising you don't get an error in the first example.

Comment: I do not know why the two differ, but I was able to verify that they produce different IL code. I have queued an edit to the question including the behavior and disassembled code.

Comment: Not a C# expert, but this question seems too abstract to be meaningful. The answer to "why" is "because the compiler said so" (or do you want a deep dive into the compiler?) Explain why you expect the same IL. Are you expecting that semantically equivalent code *ought* to produce identical IL? Is there something about this specific code that suggests it ought to produce identical IL? (By chance, would you also expect that identical code must produce identical IL?) Could it be that you want the IL to be the same to make your job easier (and that job is...)? What is the actual problem here?

Comment: @DM your comment is the answer for me. These statement are not equivalent because `pattern variables are only considered definitely assigned when the is pattern is true`. Could you post your comment as an answer. More insights from docs: `Should we elect to defer such work until later (which I advise), we could say in C# 9 beneath a not or or, pattern variables may not be declared. Then, we would have time to develop some experience that would provide insight into the possible value of relaxing that later.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments on the question:

> Could you be running into an issue with [definite assignment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/variables#definite-assignment)? [Per the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-9.0/patterns3#variable-definitions-and-definite-assignment), pattern variables are only considered definitely assigned when the `is` pattern is true. [The changelog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-9.0/patterns3) links to a number of git issues on the subject.

More insight from the docs:

> Should we elect to defer such work until later (which I advise), we could say in C# 9 beneath a `not` or `or`, pattern variables may not be declared. Then, we would have time to develop some experience that would provide insight into the possible value of relaxing that later.